# Rat trouble please help me

Tags: backyard

I found Norway rats in basement first I sealed off them coming in for the dog food but I smell them I see holes in my yard they have I think killing my wild birds that are use to living by my porch on corner of the porch I smell dead one from poison station I take out the eaten pieces whennthere small enough replace it find a rat hole drop it in fill it with dirt to see if something moves it I tried pouring ammonia done first two I saw now he just dug one four feet over so I put poisennin it covered it over with top soil found holes by back porch and corner foundation was going to fill the one by foundation with concrete being it by block onvthe house I have block stacked for a wall that fell I don’t think that’s helping when it could have been them Norway rats that pushed it over in first place making tunnels help my neighbors leave food out for there pets the lady across street dumps pots of food down Gimm so they leave her garbage alone help other guy broke new ground in back of my woods help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way we can figure out what you're trying to say; would you spend a little time breaking this into sentences and (hopefully) paragraphs? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. We're not a discussion forum. Then, please revise your question (there's an Edit link right up there) to be more clear. Use complete sentences and periods.

Comment: you posted a big pile of words without any sentence structure whatsoever ... please show that you are serious about wanting help by making the pile of words into sentences that actually make sense

Answer (score 1):

1. Leave the burrow holes and outside places alone.  Messing with them is pointless.  Rats will always find a place to live if there is food.
2. Put dog food in metal container like a trash can.
3. Leave rat poison where the dog food was.  Don't let your dogs eat it!  I had luck with that blue Dcon stuff.
4. Leave rat poison alone.  If you see it is not being eaten, move it.
5. I would leave poison only inside.  Who cares about rats outside?  They will go to your neighbors place.  Poison outside needs to be covered in a plastic box with a rat entrance or your birds or dogs will eat it.
6. After you are done w poison figure out how rats were getting in and seal it with wire mesh.  If there are a lot of possibilities then this is pointless to because they will come if there is food. If there was one main way you can close it off.

Rats might eat eggs but I do not think they hunt and kill wild birds.

Comment: They will definitely eat hatchlings too, but probably not adults.

Answer (score 1):

Rat poison kills predators, scavengers, and pets. A poisoned rat may very well go outside. A predator would eagerly pounce on a weakened poisoned rat, and a scavenger on a dead poisoned one.

I think the overall best killing method is snap traps inside boxes that exclude pets and other non target species. Keep pet food in a metal container like a 33 gal trash can with lid.